# Create Wobbling Disk

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I want to create this diagram:
[image]

I already tried with this code:

```
\begin{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.35]

\draw[fill=white] (120.7542:9.9) node (b1) {} (110.1972:11) node (b2) {};
\path (b1) -- (b2) node[] (x2) {};


\draw[fill=white] (267.0380:3.9) node (c1) {} (145:4.4) node (c2) {};
\path (c1) -- (c2) node[] (x3) {};

\draw[fill=white] (327.0380:3.9) node (d1) {} (340:13.4) node (d2) {};
\path (d1) -- (d2) node[] (x4) {};

\draw[fill=white] (10:3.9) node (e1) {} (20:13.4) node (e2) {};
\path (e1) -- (e2) node[] (x5) {};

\draw[fill=white] (10:3.9) node (f1) {} (270:13.4) node (f2) {};
\path (f1) -- (f2) node[] (x6) {};

\draw[fill=white] (10:3.9) node (h1) {} (90:13.4) node (h2) {};
\path (h1) -- (h2) node[] (x8) {};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (x4) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$e_{y}$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (x5) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$e_{x}$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (x6) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{$e_{z}$};

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (0,0) -- (x8) node[pos=1.1,fill=white,circle]{};

\draw (-4.685,-2.2) -- ++(0,10);
\draw (4.685,-2.2) -- ++(0,10);

\draw[-{Latex[length=2mm]}] (-0.9,8.65) arc (100:-120:2.9 and 0.9) node[anchor=north east,pos=1.0,label={$\dot{q}_{0}$}] {};

\draw (0,7.8) ellipse (4.685cm and 1.75cm);
\draw (-4.685,-2.2) arc (180:360:4.685 and 1.75);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

Any tikz code to produce it?.

Comment: @downvoter: please do not downvote without adding an comment with the reason for the downvote! This is a very bad behaviour!

Comment: @Downvoters: Please don't downvote below a score of -1, even if the question in its current form needs some improvement. A score of -1 is enough to show that the question needs work, anything below that is of no use. Also, if you downvote or vote to close, please leave a comment explaining why you did so, but wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close.

Comment: @Alfredo please upload, at the least, a TikZ base code to reproduce some of the drawing as a token of your effort to draw the desired picture or just to lessen the work of whoever answers it. This most certainly increases your chances of getting help, you should know that since it's not your first rodeo here at TeX-SE...

Answer (score 5):

Some parts of the diagram are recognizable, some do not seem to make sense to me. So I focus on the parts which I feel to be able to recognize. To add the other stuff you may need to load `patterns` and `decorations.pathmorphing` as well.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,intersections,bending}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{30}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,>=stealth]
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=-0.2,transform shape]
 \draw[very thick,scale=2,name path global=lower] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2,1) (-1.5,-1) (-1,-1)
  (0,-1.5) (1.5,-1) (2,-1.2) (2.1,-1.2) (0.65,1) (-0.5,0.6)};
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
 \draw[very thick,scale=2,fill=white] plot[smooth cycle] coordinates {(-2,1) (-1.5,-1) (-1,-1)
  (0,-1.5) (1.5,-1) (2,-1.2) (2.1,-1.2) (0.65,1) (-0.5,0.6)};
  \draw[thick,name path global=cylo] (180+\tdplotmainphi:1) coordinate (BL) 
    arc(180+\tdplotmainphi:360+\tdplotmainphi:1) coordinate (BR);
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=1,transform shape]
  \draw[thick,name path global=cyl]  (BL) -- (180+\tdplotmainphi:1) coordinate (TL) 
    arc(180+\tdplotmainphi:360+\tdplotmainphi:1) coordinate (TR) -- (BR);
  \draw[thick,fill=white,name path global=cylt] (0,0) coordinate (T) circle[radius=1];
  \draw[thick,->] (130:0.5) arc(130:-100:0.5) node[left,transform shape=false]{$q_0$};
 \end{scope}
 \path[name path=z axis] (0,0,2) coordinate (ZT) -- (0,0,-4) coordinate (ZB);
 \draw[dashed,thick,name intersections={of=z axis and lower,by=iz}] (T) -- (iz);
 \draw[thick,->] (T) -- (ZT);
 \draw[thick,->] (iz) -- (ZB) node[right]{$e_z$};
 \path[name path=x axis] (0,0,0) coordinate (O) -- (3,0,0);
 \path[name path=y axis] (O) coordinate (O) -- (0,3,0);
 \draw[dashed,thick,name intersections={of=x axis and cylo,by=ix}] (O) -- (ix);
 \draw[dashed,thick,name intersections={of=y axis and cylt,by=iy}] (O) -- (iy);
 \draw[thick,->] (ix) -- (3,0,0) node[right]{$e_x$};
 \draw[thick,->] (iy) -- (0,3,0) node[right]{$e_y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]